# CSS Grid, no me estaria ordenando las columnas como indico

Tags: html, css, html5, css-grid-layout

En la estructura de mi `layout`, quiero que las 3 imágenes cargadas tomen lugar en 3 columnas distintas utilizando las herramientas de `grid`, aquí lo indico `grid-template-columns: repeat (3, 250px);` y no lo logro, quedan todas las imágenes en una misma columna.

Desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo en responder!

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat (3, 250px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.item1 {
    grid-row-end: span 3;
}
.item2 {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
}
.item3 {
    grid-row-end: span 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>pinterest</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item1">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item2">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item3">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio esta todo correcto lo único es que has dejado un espacio entre repeat y el parentesis debería ser:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 250px);`